# Galois Theory cyclic extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $F\supset E$ be a Galois extension, and $a\not\in E$ an element of $F$ which is contained in every proper extension of $E$ contained in $F$.
Prove that the Galois is nilpotent and cyclic.

I can reduce this to prove that the extension $E\subset E[a]$ is normal, how can I prove this?

Comment: by "the Galois" do you mean $\rm{Gal}(F/E)$? What is your definition of nilpotent? If the group is cyclic and therefore abelian, is it not automatically nilpotent?

Answer (score 4):

Every intermediate field between $E$ and $F$, excluding the former,  contains by assumption $E(a)$, which properly contains $E$. The subgroup $H$ of the Galois group which corresponds to $E(a)$ will thus be the only maximal subgroup of $G$, because by the Galois correspondence it contains all proper subgroups of $G$.

Now a group with only one maximal subgroup is cyclic, of order a power of a prime (the latter is, I guess, what you meant by nilpotent).

**Addendum** To see the last point, let $x \in G \setminus H$. Then $\langle x \rangle$ is not contained in $H$, and thus can only be the whole of $G$. So $G$ is cyclic. Now if $G$ is infinite, and thus isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, it has infinitely many maximal subgroup. If $G$ is finite, and its order is divisible by two primes $p \ne q$, then it has (at least) two distinct maximal subgroups, namely $\langle x^{p} \rangle$ and $\langle x^{q} \rangle$.

Comment: @Aaron, just added.